# How are IOPS important when looking for a SSD?

Tags: ssd

What is the difference of IOPS in an ssd? Like if I got one with 20,000 read, and 50,000 write, compared with one thats 22,500 read, and 33,000 write?

Answer (score 2):

Purely speed - higher is better!

Early SSDs are not that much better than regular (fast) hard drives - they are simply silent and have lower power requirements... Newer SSDs on the other hand are much much faster.